# How to create default values for data structures in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a data structure like so

```
data Sample = Sample { a :: String , b :: String }
```

and a function

```
mkSample :: String -> String -> Sample
mkSample a b = Sample a b
```

I would like to provide some default values for a ,b in case the calling function does not provide them ,something like

```
mkSample :: String -> Sample
mkSample a = Sample a "test"
```

1) I dont find this solution elegant , what other alternatives do I have.
2) How do I create a mkSample for b ,as the type would be the same as the one for a .

Comment: Would `mkSample = flip Sample "test"` be better?

Comment: Fundamentally, you can't *not* provide an argument, because every function takes exactly one argument, and calling a function without an argument simply isn't possible in Haskell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data Sample = Sample { a :: String , b :: String } 
defaultSample :: Sample
defaultSample = Sample "test" "value_b"
```

Then you can use record syntax:

```
let mySample = defaultSample { b = "custom value" }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

`Maybe` is pretty much made for this kind of situation:

```
mkSample :: Maybe String -> Maybe String -> Sample
mkSample ma mb = Sample (maybe "default a" id ma) (maybe "default b" id mb)
-- NB: maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

This way you can just provide a `Nothing` if there's no available string:

```
λ> mkSample Nothing (Just "World!")
Sample "default a" "World!"
λ> mkSample (Just "Hello,") Nothing
Sample "Hello," "default b"
λ> mkSample Nothing Nothing
Sample "default a" "default b"
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, I tried it out, But i think ill go ahead an implement the solution above ,as it works slightly better for my code